# Trim a file name in Unix

Tags: unix, filenames, trim

I have a file with name

```
ROCKET_25_08:00.csv
```

I want to trim the name of the file to

```
ROCKET_25_.csv
```

I tried `mv` but `mv` is not what I required because there will be cases where the files may be more than one.

I want the name till the second `_`.

How to get that in unix.

Please advise.

Comment: What do you mean by *cases where the files may be more than one*?

Comment: there can be two files 
ROCKET_25_08:00.csv and ROCKET_25_08:04.csv

Comment: In that case I want to trim both the files in one shot.

Comment: You can't have two files with the same name. Do you want to combine the files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some utilities that provide more flexible renaming. But one solution that won't use anything other but included UNIX tools (like sed) would be:

```
ls -d * | sed -re 's/^([^_]*_[^_]*_)(.*)(\....)$/mv -v \1\2\3 \1\3/' | bash
```

This will only work in one directory, it won't process subdirectories.

Answer (score 0):

It's not at all clear what you are actually trying to do, but if you just want to remove text between the last underscore and the period, you can do:

```
f=ROCKET_25_08:00.csv
echo ${f%_*}_.csv
```